# SQL - Return a value sum only once when grouped

Tags: sql-server

I want to count the unique record of a string but grouping by dates, and if the string already appeared previously on a group it shouldn't be counted anymore.

I've tried using distinct and it does show the unique count of the record but the record is counted again on every month.

**Actual and minified SQL query:**

```
select
date,
count(distinct d.name) as count

from ...

group by date
```

**Sample and desired output**

[Image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ytoPm.png)

Comment: please share sample data and expected output

Comment: Your script seem ok to me. What issue you are facing?

Comment: Hi @DervişKayımbaşıoğlu, I've just shared

Comment: Hi @mkRabbani, the issue is that it's counting uniquely every month, the idea is to count only the first time it appears and dont count it anymore.
I've uploaded same sample and the desired output.

Answer (score 1):

Grab unique names and tag them with the earliest date. At that point it's just a matter of regrouping the resulting rows by date. Each name will uniquely correspond to only one date as desired:

```
with data as (select name, min("date") as dt from T group by name)
select dt, count(name) as cnt from data group by dt;
```

If you still need to see the original dates even when no names are counted, then flag each row according to whether it should be counted and then count the flags per date:

```
with data as (
    select *,
        case when "date" = min("date") over (partition by name)
            then 1 end as flag
    from T
)
select "date", count(flag) as cnt
from data
group by "date";
```

Comment: Hi @shawnt00, could you clarify what this query is doing?

Answer (score 0):

So you want the name only count once:

```
SELECT COUNT(u.name) as name_count, u.[date]
FROM (
  SELECT d.name,MIN(d.date) AS [date]
  FROM yourTable d
  GROUP BY d.name) u
GROUP BY u.[date];
```

Answer (score 0):

You can add a ROW_NUMBER() that is Partitioned by `name` and ordered by `date` and add a WHERE clause that only returns the rows with Row_Number = 1.

Comment: Tab, but what if the `name` doesn't appear on the first group theoretically row_number = 1 ?

Comment: @riner then it will be "counted" in the first group where it DOES appear.   Every name WILL have a row_number = 1, and it will be associated with the first date where that name appears.  mkRabbani has posted an example of what I am suggesting.

Comment: Ok thank you, I'm trying to implement that approach

Answer (score 0):

You can check this following option-

```
SELECT A.Date,COUNT(B.[Name]) Count
FROM
(
    SELECT DISTINCT Date FROM your_table
)A
LEFT JOIN
(
    SELECT * FROM
    (
        SELECT  *,ROW_NUMBER() OVER(PARTITION BY [Name] ORDER BY Date)   RN
        FROM your_table
    )A WHERE RN = 1
)B ON A.Date = B.Date
GROUP BY A.Date
```

But the best option if I modify a bit the concept from Shawnt00 is as below-

```
SELECT A.Date,COUNT(B.[Name]) Count
FROM
(
    SELECT DISTINCT Date FROM your_table
)A
LEFT JOIN
(
    SELECT [Name],MIN(Date) Date FROM your_table GROUP BY [Name]
)B ON A.Date = B.Date
GROUP BY A.Date
```

Both case the output will be-

```
Date        Count
20190101    2
20190201    0
20190301    1
```

Comment: Hi Rabbani, I'm getting error 3504 (Selected non-aggregate values must be part of the associated group). I'm still debugging to understand if it's related to my query.

Comment: Do you make any changes?  Please give the query.